# Blooming Problems 2

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Capcom referenced me by purpose of the goddess of my name

You can find me as a different entity helpful to see the tame

Change my second letter for both love and hate

Are my petals like that for coincidence or by a strange fate?

Name the flower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the flower

> Iris?

Capcom referenced me by purpose of the goddess of my name

> In the Capcom game Mega Man X, there is a character Iris (named after Iris, the greek goddess of rainbows and messenger of the gods).

You can find me as a different entity helpful to see the tame

> Iris is also a part of the eye.

Change my second letter for both love and hate

> If you change 'r' to 's', you get Isis which is both a terrorist group (hate) and the egyptian goddess associated with motherhood (love).

Are my petals like that for coincidence or by a strange fate?

> (answer by **nikki**) The iris dataset which includes the flowers' petal and sepal lengths and widths.

Comment: The last hint may be talking about rot13(Gur vevf qngnfrg juvpu vapyhqrf gur sybjref' crgny naq frcny yratguf naq jvqguf.)

Comment: Yes, amazing job, also Capcom used it a lot of times